# Atlas - Export only certain pages

Tags: qgis, atlas

I would like to export only certain pages from an atlas.
For instance: I have an atlas with 37 pages, and I update pages 3,5,7-10. I would like to export those pages for reprint to a single PDF.

Comment: So, what is keeping you from doing so? What have you tried? How were the results not satisfactory?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Option 1**

Click Atlas --> Atlas Settings

Here, you have chosen which layer composes the atlas.

You can add a filter setting by expression. Put something like `'name' LIKE "feature3" OR 'name' LIKE "feature5"`, refering to an attribute identifying thoses features.

This way, only the concerned features will be exported in the atlas

**Option 2**

Click Atlas --> Print Atlas

Use your favorite "Print to PDF" tool (depends on your OS, mainly)

Select the pages you want to print