# Easyest way to switch between two layouts in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layouts

I'm creating two layouts in QGIS. Because size (A4 + A3) and orientation are different, I want the legend to be in a different place and different order, as shown in the pictures below. The pink "Legende" will change its size depending on the amount of items shown in the linked map.

We have to create many maps manually showing different extents for various customers. Depending on the area shown, we choose the format. Most customers will need a map of both sizes (A4 and A3). This means that we have to fill out all the boxes with "text" and maybe also adapt de pink legend the same way twice.

What's the easiest way to switch between those two layouts without retyping too much manually?
[image: A3]

[image: A4]

Comment: Add a second page to your layout.

Comment: If you are going to use those vary same layouts many times, you could have the text in both be dynamic referring to an attribute table value that you enter once.  You might even look at a map atlas to see if that can be used to easily update text, legend and extents, even if at any one time you only print out one set for a customer.

Comment: @Matt: At the moment I use two different layouts, one for each paper size. I'm not sure about adding a second page to the layout. Wouldn't it slow down everything and always export both pages?

Comment: @John: I didn't find this option in the main properties of the label item where the text should be written. Could you explain how I can do this? I see the problem, that if there are several polygons, maybe also the text would be repeated many times?

Comment: Do these links help?  Dynamic text, dynamic print layouts and their use in map atlases can save a lot of time.   https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/435408/create-dynamic-text-in-legend-for-visible-layer-on-map-layout-using-sql-expressi and https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/dynamic_layout.html

Comment: @John: Because no customer receives the same extent, and one customer also doesn't receive the same extent multi times, I think it makes no sense for us to use atlas?

Comment: @Motti Once set up a Map Atlas can be set to export only the maps you want.  You can add features/records to your coverage layer as well and thus export new maps using just these if you want.  The extents, dynamic text, legends, labels, export file names, etc. based on the coverage layer will update.   Here's one link I found for only exporting the maps you want as I don't have one here at home to test.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432603/atlas-export-only-certain-pages.